# What are repositories, containers and services in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony

I am learning how to work Symfony 2.5. But I have some questions to which I don't find answers. Maybe they are not related only to Symfony, but I don't know.
What are:

- repositories (or repository classes)
- containers
- services

Comment: Have you read through the docs? http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a brief overview.  The docs are much more detailed and the best way to learn it is to read the docs and go through one of the tutorials that build a site from start to end.

Let's say you have an entity called Product.  This will be an object in php and also a table in the database.  Each row in the table is a separate product and you define it in an entity php file as follows:

```
<?php
// src/Company/ProductBundle/Entity/Product.php

namespace Company\ProductBundle\Entity;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Company\ProductBundle\Entity\ProductRepository")
 */
class Product
{
    /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
    * @ORM\Id
    * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
    */
    protected $id;

    /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=50)
    */
    protected $type;

    /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=20)
    */
    protected $color;
}
```

Repository - This is a naming convention for a sub folder of the entity folder and it will hold queries related to a specific entity.  There is one repository for each entity.  The repository is defined as:

```
// src/Company/ProductBundle/Entity/Repository/ProductRepository.php
namespace Company\ProductBundle\Entity\Repository;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class ProductRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function findProductByColor($args)
    {
        $color = $args['color'];

        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
              ->orderBy('p.type', 'ASC')
              ->where('p.color = ?1')
              ->setParameter(1, $color);

        return $qb->->getQuery()->getResult();
    }
}
```

It can be called in a controller using the entity manager:

```
$result = $em->getRepository('AcmeBundle:Product')->
    findProductByColor(array('color' => $color);
```

A problem with this is that is creates bulk in the controller because you need the entity manager defined and can lead to more manipulation in the controller, and you also need to include a 'use' line for the entity in the controller.  That's where services come in.

Services - In the above example, you need to use the entity manager in a controller to load a specific Product collection and this is not the preferred method.  Business logic should not reside in a controller which is why services have become more popular.  Services are a global way of creating php objects.

After a service is created, you can call it by simplying using something like this in your controller, or any other file that needs access to this entity:

```
$redproducts = $$this->get('products_red');
```

To create a service, look at the [symfony docs here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html).

Container - I think you are referring to a service container or the dependency injection container, also known as the DIC.  It is is a special object in Symfony that manages the instantiation of services inside an application.  There is only one and all services are available within it.  You will not create a container, especially if you are new and not creating bundles that other will use.  Read more about the [service container here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html).

Answer (score 1):

repositories - http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-objects.html#custom-repositories is about entities, but you will get the idea of repositories

services - http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html

Comment: Please consider changing the repository link to: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-objects.html#custom-repositories It is unfortunate that the somehwat dated 2.0 documentation seem to come up first in google searches.

Comment: And what about containers?

Comment: check http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Container_%28abstract_data_type%29 and then go back to the http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html